# How to get the creator of the event?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want get the creator of a `Google Calendar Event`, so I browsed the documentation page, specifically [this section](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) and I saw that there is an object called `creator`, but how can I extract this from an event taken by the calendar?

My code looks like this:

```
foreach ($events->getItems() as $event)
{
    $appointment = [
        'start_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->start->getDateTime())),
        'end_datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($event->end->getDateTime())),
        'notes' => $event->getDescription(),
        'title' => $event->getSummary(),
        'id_user' => $operator_id,
        'id_google_calendar' => $event->getId(),
        'attendee' => []
        'creator' => ??????
    ];
}
```

Comment: I am sorry you question is unclear what exactly is the issue with the code you are using currently?

Comment: @DaImTo I just want to know how can I get the `creator` of the event.. which method should I call from the object `$event`?

Comment: what happens if you do $events->Creator?  Have you tried outputting all of event and see what it contains?

Comment: @DaImTo yep I tried and the field is `[creator]` and I also tried as you suggested: `$event->creator()` but I get: `Call to undefined method Google_Event::creator()`, maybe is `$event->getCreator()` I didn't find any reference of this method in the doc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these two options should work remember the creator will need to be uppercase first letter.

```
$event->Creator()  

$event->getCreator()
```

If I recall

```
$event->Creator['email'] should also work.
```

This library is generated programmatic via the Discovery services API.  The documentation has not been generated there for a lot of it will not show up in the documentation its an experience thing.   When you have worked with the library for a while you get to know how its designed.

Comment: @DalmTo so essentially for some method I need to guess?

Comment: Its not really a matter of guessing its just using the name of the parameter and adding get in front of it.   I normally dont bother using the gets.   I just call it using the third option i posted.

Comment: @DalmTo okay, thanks for your time and your knowledge. In the past I had already read one of your articles and they helped me a lot, it's a pleasure to meet you, I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
foreach ($events->getItems() as $event)
{
    var_dump($event->getCreator());
}
```

(Tried in my code). See official documentation for this at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Event.html

Comment: thanks but where did you take this method? I can't find in the doc

Comment: @sfarzoso included the link in the answer